# unable to access radio button ng-model within controller : Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I know there are simalar questions on stackoverflow like this, but they still don't solve the issue.

I have a list of three radio buttons which when their ng-model is stated, I still cannot access their value in the related controller.

```
<input type="radio" name="searchType" value="active" ng-model="radioValue" class="radio-buttons">

<input type="radio" name="searchType" value="ammSd" ng-model="radioValue" class="radio-buttons">

<input type="radio" name="searchType" value="ammEd" ng-model="radioValue" class="radio-buttons">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" ng-click="search()">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
</button>
```

The Controller :

```
$scope.search = function(){

    alert($scope.radioValue);
};
```

The result I keep getting back in 'undefined'.

Any ideas?

Comment: `<input type="radio" name="searchType" value="active" ng-model="radioValue[0]" class="radio-buttons">`

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your code into a jsFiddle and it worked just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/kVGF9/

If nothing is selected though, it will return undefined. If you want to have one pre-selected just assign it in your controller:

```
$scope.radioValue = "ammSd";
$scope.search = function(){
    alert($scope.radioValue);
};
```

Comment: I set the value like you mentioned and the radio button is pre selected, but when i change the slection the value remains 'ammSd' for each radio button.

Comment: Please include more of your code, because the jsFiddle I linked works just fine.